# Cannot commit on repository from one specific location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a very strange svn problem.
I have a repository called trunk. I can commit on it from all the machine that I tested, except one (and it is of course these machine from which I want to commit...).
The machine on which the commit fails is the one hosting my Jenkins server.
I try the following commands :

```
svn commit -m "commit message"  

svn commit -m "commit message" --username user1 --password *******

svn commit -m "commit message" --username user1 --password ******* --non-
interactive  

svn commit -m "commit message" --username user1 --password ******* --no-
auth-cache  

svn commit -m "commit message" --username user1 --password ******* --non-
interactive --no-auth-cache
```

But they asked me the following question (if interactive) :

```
Authentication realm: <svn://hostname:3690> XXXX Repository
Username:
```

And, whatever I enter as user and password, they all failed with the following error :

```
svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: Authentication error from server: Username not found
```

I have exactly the same problem with tortoiseSVN.

What I don't understand is the svn://hostname:3690. The hostname is correct, but the port is not. I guess the error comes from there, but I have no idea how to correct it.

If someone has an idea...

Thank you,

Seb

Comment: What's logged to the server's log?

Comment: There is no error in the server's log.